# How to cut video resolution from 3840x2160 to 2184x1680 in VLC

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, cut

So I have a video 3840x2160 resolution and I want to cut out a part of it. So I'd only have the upperleft 2184x1680 pixels. Can that be done in VLC?

Answer (score 0):

**Non-Permanent Crop (VLC)**

If you want a non-permanent crop, select `Extended Settings` in VLC (represented as an icon that looks like several option sliders):

[image: VLC - Extended Settings - Screenshot]

And switch to the  `Video Effects` tab, then the `Crop` sub-tab. Set your preferences accordingly:

[image: VLC - Video Crop Sub-tab - Screenshot]

If my math isn't off, you will want 1656 for the `Right` option and 480 for the `Bottom` option.

**Permanent Crop (ffmpeg)**

If you want a more permanent solution, you should consider use a program a such as [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) (Windows builds are available [here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)). You can then potentially use the `crop` filter like so:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=2184:1680:0:0" out.mp4
```

In this case, 2184 and 1680 represent (respectively) the desired width and height of the output video , while `0:0` tells `ffmpeg` to start from the upper left corner.

---

*References*

- [Best VLC Hidden Feature - Use VLC as Free Video Editor](https://www.videoproc.com/video-editor/edit-video-with-vlc.htm)
- [How can I crop a video with ffmpeg?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg)